# Move window to new desktop in Windows 10?

Tags: virtual-desktop, windows-10-preview

In the current Windows 10 tech preview, you can finally add new "virtual" desktops and quickly jump between them.

But is it possible to move an open window (for example a browser) from one desktop to another and if so, how?

Comment: There is a tool for that: https://github.com/Eun/MoveToDesktop

Comment: https://github.com/mzomparelli/zVirtualDesktop

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open Task View, either by clicking on the icon in your task bar or by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then right click on the application/window you would like to move to another virtual desktop and make your selection from the **Move to** context menu.

[image: Move to in Windows 10 Technical Preview Task View]

Note that you will only see the applications open on the current desktop in task view, so either open Task View from the virtual desktop it is running on, or you can change the "focus" to a different virtual desktop by mousing over it's picture (but not clicking it) at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: No problem @Thomas, I'd recommend keeping an eye on Windows 10 patch notes, as a lot of people have requested the ability to drag windows to different desktops and/or adding the move option to right click menus other than in Task View and that may well happen at some stage.

Comment: yeah, I gotta imagine there are more intuitive ways, not that its bad how it's done now. Would be great if the same context menu would be accessible on a regular window, not just in the Task View.

Comment: Also it needs hotkeys. Ability to move to desktop by number or even with arrows to the right or the left

Comment: You can now click and drag them to other desktops... would also prefer a keyboard shortcut though too.

Comment: *its* picture, please?